# argparse is not returning expected value for store_true

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm running Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) and getting strange results from argparse. Despite the -x, the value of trainandexecute=False

```
def get_parameters():
    startup = '-x -b'
    sys.argv = startup.split(' ')
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-x',       '--trainandexecute', action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-b',       '--debug',           action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-d',       '--rundate',         action='store')
    print(ap.parse_args())
    return vars(ap.parse_args())
get_parameters()
```

This returns the following output. Notet that trainandexecute=False despite the -x flag.

```
Namespace(debug=True, execute=False, train=False, trainandexecute=False)
{'train': False,
 'execute': False,
 'trainandexecute': False,
 'debug': True}
```

However, this test works in the next Jupyter cell and that it is not my environment:

```
def get_test_parameters():
    startup = '-b -x'
    sys.argv = startup.split(' ')
    print(sys.argv)
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-x',       '--x',         action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-b',       '--debug',     action='store_true')
    print(ap.parse_args())
    return vars(ap.parse_args())
```

So the output of:

```
get_test_parameters()
```

is:

```
['-b', '-x']                   # print(sys.argv)
Namespace(debug=False, x=True) # print(ap.parse_args())
{'x': True, 'debug': False}    # return vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I'm bifflesnickered...

Comment: `sys.argv` would not be `['-x', '-v']` if the program was actually called with those arguments: `sys.argv[0]` would be the program name, and the arguments would start at `[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
sys.argv = startup.split(' ')
```

The first value in `sys.argv` is treated as the name of the script, not as an option. Try running `ap.parse_args(startup.split())` - and you will see the right answer.

Incidentally, do not pass any parameters to `split()`. If you pass `" "` and you have more than one consecutive space, the result of the split will have empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better test framework:

```
def get_parameters(argv=None):
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-x',       '--trainandexecute', action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-b',       '--debug',           action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-d',       '--rundate',         action='store')
    args = ap.parse_args(argv))     # if None, parses sys.argv[1:]
    print(args)
    return vars(args)

get_parameters('-x -b'.split())
```

You can modify `sys.argv[1:]` instead.  By passing `argv` through your function, you can test several ways.